# Firefox: Pocket icon in address bar

Tags: firefox

After the upgrade to Firefox 57, which resets the toolbar, I notice I have a Pocket icon in my location bar.  Do not want.

I am able to remove this Pocket icon using a right-click menu.  Good.

This leaves me confused.  How would I be supposed to add Pocket back, if I ever wanted to use it?  I can't see Pocket in the Customization window.  It does not show up in Extensions, and if I go to Preferences and search "Pocket", no results appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The address bar also has an overflow button **⋯** which contains various page-related tools, including Pocket. Each item has a right-click menu allowing you to add it back to the main bar.

---

The layout is stored as JSON in the `browser.pageActions.persistedActions` setting (about:config):

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "ids": ["bookmark", "bookmarkSeparator", "copyURL", "emailLink", "sendToDevice",
          "pocket", "screenshots", "webcompat-reporter-button"],
  "idsInUrlbar": ["pocket", "bookmark"]
}
```

Comment: I found the UI after a minute looking in about:config, and realizing what idsInUrlbar meant :).  I'd looked at the "..." menu once before, but I forgot about it, particularly as an alternative way to get to Pocket.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I attempted to edit this in about:config to no luck, but found an easier method that doesn't involve a warning screen about voiding the warranty.

In the address bar there is an icon of three dots arranged horizontally. Left click it to reveal a menu which includes an item for Pocket. Right click this menu item to reveal a menu with one item: "Add to Address Bar" -- click this to put it back in place.

Comment: I will try to clarify the answer, which begins "The address bar also has an overflow button ⋯ which contains various page-related tools. Each item has a right-click menu allowing you to add it back to the main bar..."